# Is it possible to allow a user to attach a file in a .pdf form?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, forms

I created an interactive `.pdf` in Indesign, but I want to ad an option to let the user attach a file that he or she has on his computer. Is that possible?

Comment: what exactly do you mean be *"attach a picture"*. Like drag an drop a picture in a container in the PDF?

Comment: In Acrobat Pro you can add an image but I presume you want something along the lines of a form field that can be used by someone with only Adobe Reader?

Comment: If the user has wants to attach an image to the form e.g.  a certificate of proof, couldn't they just email it as a separate attachment along with the pdf?

Comment: this feature only works in acrobat pro if your user is using Acrobat reader they can only import PDF's in the form

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be possible but would require scripting.

Steps:

> - Open up the Content Panel via *Tools > Content Panel*
> - Using the 'Add a button' tool draw a button to the size the image field needs to be
> - Double click the button to enter into the button's properties
> - Go to the Actions tab
> - Next to Select Action choose 'Run a JavaScript'
> - Click Add
> - Copy & Paste the following JavaScript in the window:
>
>   event.target.buttonImportIcon();
> - OK
> - Go to the Options tab
> - Under Layout choose 'Icon Only'
> - Investigate any other options you need then..
> - Close
>
> Test using the Selection Tool (black arrow tool). Note that when
>   browsing for the image you are not restructed to PDF's as you can
>   change the file type in the lower right to say JPEG or PNG etc.

Source: https://answers.acrobatusers.com/adding-image-field-form-q41825.aspx#postComments41835